# How to make a shipping request to chronopost using soap and nodejs

Tags: node.js, soap

I've had trouble getting to make a simple request with node-soap and chronopost (shipping platform) soap api.

the first thing I did was to follow the basic node-soap example but it just fails miserably without any real USEFUL error from chronopost.

Here's what I have:

```
const soap = require('soap')

const client = await soap.createClientAsync(
  'https://ws.chronopost.fr/shipping-cxf/ShippingServiceWS?wsdl'
)

client.shippingV6(...somedata, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return handleErr(); // it always fails
  }
  handleResult();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempt it seems like chronopost api uses special root attributes (who knows why) and you need to craft the options on node-soap that actually fit their needs (yay..)

Here's what works for me

```
const createClientShippingServiceWS = async () => {
  const wsdlOptions = {
    envelopeKey: 'soapenv',
    overrideRootElement: {
      namespace: 'cxf',
      xmlnsAttributes: [
        {
          name: 'xmlns:cxf',
          value: 'http://cxf.shipping.soap.chronopost.fr/'
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  return await soap.createClientAsync(
    'https://ws.chronopost.fr/shipping-cxf/ShippingServiceWS?wsdl',
    wsdlOptions
  )
}
```

Also what's the point of getting the wsdl if node-soap can't event figure how to make the response??

Thanks chronopost for being stuck in 2008